# preg_replace() all occurances

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to create a script that will remove all comments from a file. My current regex is this:

```
$new = preg_replace_all("/(\/\*.*\*\/)/s", "", $contents);
```

Which matches (and removes) anything between `/*` and `*/`

The problem becomes apparent when the contents of a file is something like this for example:

```
/* First comment */ 
first_function();

/* Second comment */ 
second_function();
```

Instead of removing the first and the second comment and leaving both function calls, my regular expression matches everything from the first `/*` to the last `*/` and thus removing the `first_function()` call entirely.

I imagine a solution would be to replace my `.*` (which matches anything) with something that would say match anything **until you get to `*/`**. But I don't know how to write that. I expected it to be something like `[^\*\/]` but it doesn't work as expected.

What is the correct regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very very close. All you needed was to use the *non-greedy match* character `?` after your `.*`, as follows:

```
$new = preg_replace_all("/(\/\*.*?\*\/)/s", "", $contents);
                                 ^
                                 ^
                                 ^
                                 ^
```

Just one question mark is all you needed…

See this at work [here](http://regex101.com/r/tY7iC4)

Comment: Non-greedy match character... I like its name :P Thanks.